# length of URL too long(greater than 2083) when Add Git

Tags: ibm-cloud

I just create a bluemix account. First I try to create an ASP.NET app, then start coding with Git.

I get the "length of URL too long" error when click Add Git.

[image]

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your issue: I've just created a new CF App in ASP.NET named '*testumasp*'. Then I clicked on 'Add Git' from my Bluemix Dashboard and I correctly created the Git Repository on DevOps Services. Try again with a different app name and if the problem persists I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the 
     upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support 
     widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of 
     assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I was using the http proxy yesterday, that might be the issue.